# How to remove taxonomy base from url

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I'm basically trying to remove taxonomy bases from my urls e.g from this:
http://www.example.com/posttype/tax/term1/tax/term2

To this: 
http://www.example.com/postype/term1/term2

I've read many posts stating that this is impossible to achieve. However I've come across many sites that have achieved this. So I'm asking this question in hope that someone out here has managed to achieve this.

My rewrite code:

```
function add_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $new_vars = array( 'vehicle-type', 'fuel', 'color', 'status', 'gearbox', 'interior', 'exterior', 'safety', 'extra', 'location', 'vehicle-year', 'model' );

    return array_merge( $new_vars, $query_vars );
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars' );`
function add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $new_rules = array(
        'vehicles/vehicle_status/(.+?)/vehicle_fuel_type/(.+?)/vehicle_color/(.+?)/vehicle_status/(.+?)/vehicle_gearbox/(.+?)/vehicle_interior_feature/(.+?)/vehicle_exterior_feature/(.+?)/vehicle_safety_feature/(.+?)/vehicle_extra/(.+?)/vehicle_location/(.+?)/vehicle_year/(.+?)/vehicle_model/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=vehicles&vehicle_status=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&vehicle_fuel_type=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&vehicle_color=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&vehicle_status=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&vehicle_gearbox=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&vehicle_interior_feature=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&vehicle_exterior_feature=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&vehicle_safety_feature=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8) .'&vehicle_extra=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(9) .'&vehicle_location=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(10) . '&vehicle_year=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(11) . '&vehicle_model=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(12)' ) ;
    }
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');`
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings -> permalinks in wordpress panel. Select permalink structure as you want.

Comment: I meant I want to do this for only custom taxonomies

Comment: Try Permalink manager plugin which has a more permalink settings.